Unable to reference a function from a javascript controller with hotwire/stimulus
I'm not sure if this is a local setup issue, or if it's a code issue, but I'm having trouble using a new function on an existing controller. It's possible this controller was never successfully being imported in the first place. Even after having the controller specified in the layout and referencing it in the view, I'm being told that it's referencing an undefined method:

I have done the following for startup:
$ rm -rf public/assets
$ rails assets:precompile
$ bundle install
$ rails s

Here's what I have
  # application.html.erb
  <body data-controller="modal data">
    
    <%= yield %>

  </body>

// javascript/controllers/modal_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["container", "background", "panel", "terms"]

  changeVisibility(element, visible) {
    console.log(element, hidden);
    if (visible) {
      $(element).on('click', function () {
        $('#terms_modal').removeClass('hidden');
      });
    } else {
      $(element).on('click', function () {
        $('#terms_modal').addClass('hidden');
      });
    }
  };
}

# app/views/home/girl.html.erb
<p>You agree to our <a class="text-red open_terms" data-action="click->modal#changeVisibility('terms_modal', true)">Terms and conditions</a></p>

// app/javascript/controllers/index.js


// This file is auto-generated by ./bin/rails stimulus:manifest:update
// Run that command whenever you add a new controller or create them with
// ./bin/rails generate stimulus controllerName

import { application } from "./application"

// other controllers

import ModalController from "./modal_controller"
application.register("modal", ModalController)

Edit:
I've confirmed that the controller is being successfully registered and loaded!
  connect() {
    console.log("connected");
  };

And the file is being watched because that is a new function in the controller.


I may be wrong, but I've never seen the option to pass arguments to Stimulus method directly like that. You need to define the action and route it to the Stimulus method, and then pass params to it additionaly. Check out this doc guide from Stimulus.

Ohhh I see! So the problem isn’t that it can’t find the function, but that it doesn’t know the params? I’ll see if I define the event params separately if that helps, thanks!

Yup, you need to pass them separately, you can't pass them directly to the method call

Let me know if you want me to write a more detailed answer

@crodev while I'm sure you're right about passing arguments and I do need to update, unfortunately I still get Error: Action "click->modal#changeVisibility()" references undefined method "changeVisibility()"

I was just calling it wrong. Got the clue from @crodev that I was passing arguments incorrectly. Even after establishing them as data params, I was still calling the function as click->modal#changeVisibility() when it should have just been click->modal#changeVisibility
